# Is there a way to control local tool(CATIA/Office) by webbrowser?

Tags: webbrowser-control, catia

Currently I am working on the development of CATIA by C++ and Automation Interface. Everything is based on local environment of every client machine. After updating our program, clients have to deploy it manually after receiving the updated one.

We are considering if there is a way we could put our program on the server, and we assign the authorizations to the specific clients to access it. They still need install CATIA in their local machine, but our customization programs are on the website.

Our program is based on COM component, so this is a priority.

Any feasible idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm developing programs for Catia too (VB .NET) and there might be a solution to use webbrowser to manage the programs but I'm unable to help with that :)
Instead what I use is selfdeveloped feature which updates the tools exe files on client from network storage or FTP.

Think of it as algorithm which searches certain folders or storage and decides if the program should update itself and lets the user know. Then you run the updater which is not part of the tool (separate program) and he make the changes on the main exe (copy files, config, remove add etc.)

This way you don't have to take care of the deployment and the user only clicks the update. That's it :)

Comment: Program updating is one of the issue I want to solve, and you're right that we could develop another program to solve this issue.

Comment: But for the larger picture, we want to develop an online website to contain all the customized programs we developed, and they could be assigned to specific clients. Also the website is a convenient and infficient window to show to the clients or customers. It might be a complete and profittable product to join together.